Does my 2008 Ford f150 need a chip key or does it have a PATS?
I have a 2008 Ford F-150 and I lost my key am I going to need a chip key to start it up or is there a PATS system?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

According to this site, most Fords (including your 2008 F-150) use a chipped key which operates an e-PATS system in your truck. This will most likely take a professional locksmith or taking it to the dealer to get it programmed, though. Without a programmed key in your possession, the key will need other means to get the truck to recognize it.
